# React - Image paths changing to relative when address bar entered directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click a route link everything works fine, the images have the correct path in the DOM, and the images load.

But if I type the URL into the address bar, including the route suffix, e.g. example.com/services, the image paths on the services route page change to include the "/services" prefix and therefore results in 404 on the GET request. If I then click on the route link directly, the DOM updates and the correct path is set and the images load.

On services page:

```
<li>
    <Link exact to="/services">
        Services{" "}
    </Link>
```

My App.js

```
const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Routes />
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This because of the difference in how **Server-Side** and **Client-Side** routing is handled. When you click a link within your UI, such as the `/services` link given by your list element, *JavaScript runs which manipulates the URL in the address bar, without causing a page refresh*. **React Router then performs a page transition on the client side**, as opposed to sending an http request to the server. However, when you put in a url directly in the address bar within a browser, such as http://localhost:3000/services, the browser will make an **http request to your `/services` route on your server**. However, your `/services` route, on the server, hasn't been set up to handle such an http request so this results in the corresponding 404 error. This is why hash routing was invented, to avoid making an http request to your server, since most servers doesn't understand hash routes like: `/#/services` since server routes are typically configured not to have hashes in them.

So if want your `/services` URL to work correctly on both the server-side and client-side, you need to *set up the `/services` route on both your server and client side code bases.* On your server I would also suggest creating an error handler to catch all 404 errors and have this route redirect the user back to your home or index page. This will allows users to avoid the default 404 page generated from your server. Typically, a good User Interface experience will have users navigating to different pages by clicking links as opposed to putting in the URL manually since it's generally unreasonable to expect someone to memorize an exact route.

Hopefully that helps clarify things!

Comment: Hi, the page does load, it is only the images which have the /route/ prefix breaking them. Also I need this for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Please insert `/` prefix to your image source. It always makes sure your image point to root of your domain.
Example: https://example.com or https://example.com/contact

```
<img src="/static/my-banner.png" />
```

Your image source alway is https://example.com/static/my-banner.png